# Database connection is not working properly in the child class Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm creating a small app in OOP with node.js.

So, I've already create a database class with connecting the application to MySql database and the connection is working fine inside the database class. But when I try to use the connection in the child class which is called table class, the connection is not working properly when I call the method created in that table class. Its always undefined. I'll share my code below to show how I use the coding for this application.

**This is the database class**
I use events module to make the application event base

```
const mysql = require('mysql')

const EventEmitter = require('events');

class Database extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(host, user, password, database) {
        // Calling the instaces of EventEmitter module
        super();

        // Initializing instances for the HRS database to be interacted with its 
        this.host = host;
        this.user = user;
        this.passowrd = password;
        this.database = database;
        this.connection = null;
    }

    // Creating a custom method to connect and interact with the database
    openConnect() {
        this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: this.host,
            user: this.user,
            password: this.passowrd,
            database: this.database
        });
        this.connection.connect((err) => {
            if(err) this.emit('error', err);
            this.emit('connected', `Database connected successfully`);
        });
    }

    // This method used to create SQL query to interact with the Database
    customQuery(sql, callback) {
        this.connection.query(sql, (err, query) => {
            if(err) callback(err);
            callback(null, query);
        });
    }

    // Closing the connection with the database (HRS)
    closeConnection() {
        this.connection.end(err => {
            if(err) this.emit('error', err);
            this.emit('closed', 'The connection closed with the database successfully');
        });
    }
}

// Finally exporting the Database class
module.exports = Database;
```

**This is the Table class**
I'm trying to reusable table creation class using the method which I've created in the database class

```
const Database = require('../models/db_class');

class Table extends Database {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    createTable(table, colls, callback) {
        this.on('connected', (msg) => {
            this.customQuery(`CREATE TABLE '${table} (${colls})'`, (err, newTable) => {
                if(err) {
                    this.emit('error', err);
                    callback(err);
                } else {
                    this.emit('tableCreated', newTable);
                    callback(null, newTable);
                }
            });
        });
        this.on('closed', (error) => {
             console.log(error)
        });
        this.on('error', (error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }
}

module.exports = Table;
```

**This is the index.js file **

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

// Requiring the module of Database class
const Database = require('./models/db_class');

// Requiring the Table class as a exported module
const Table = require('./models/table_class');

// Creating the object of Database class
const database = new Database(process.env.HOST, process.env.USER, process.env.PASSWORD, process.env.DATABASE);

const table = new Table();

database.openConnect();
database.checkDatabaseExists();

database.on('connected', (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);

    database.on('dbExists', (result) => {
        if(result.length > 0) {
            console.log(`Database exists ${JSON.stringify(result[0].SCHEMA_NAME)}`);
            
            table.on('tableCreated', (tableCreated) => {
                console.log(tableCreated);
            });
            
            database.closeConnection();
        } else {
            database.createDatabase();
            database.closeConnection();
        }
    });
});

table.createTable('users', '_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL');

database.on('dbCreated', (result) => {
    console.log(`Database created ${JSON.stringify(result[0].SCHEMA_NAME)}`);
});

database.on('error', (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
});

database.on('closed', (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
});

// Requiring the routes folder to the application index
app.use('/', require('./routes/main-routes'));

// Creating a server to listen requests
app.listen(process.env.SERVER_PORT, () => {
    console.log("Listening requests on port 3000")
});
```

My issue is, customQuery method is not working properly when I use the method in the table class and the createTable method is also now working when I call it in the index.js file.

My problem is, where could be the issue? is it coming from the connection with the database or is there something wrong with the way I call the methods between the child and parent classes?

It's appreciate a lot, if you could provide me the answer in events base emitting the customQuery method as well

Thank you!

Comment: Who do you expect the database connection is created in/passed to the `Table` class?

Comment: @t.niese I was thinking that, when I extends the database class and call the super() method in the constructor of the Table class, could automatically be pass the database connection from the Database class.

Comment: But the connection is created for an instance of the Database class, but you could have as many of those instance as you want. So if you have  `const database1 = new Database(hostA, userA, ....)` and `const database2 = new Database(hostB, userB, ....)` how should `const table = new Table()` know which of these two databases to use?